# flutter keyboard does not close

Tags: flutter, keyboard

I developed an application with Flutter, but I have 1 problem when I test it on real devices, the keyboard does not turn off! I press the back button, it closes and reopens
[image]

Comment: can you please more Explain .. or add your code .. thank you